# How does compiler know if a variable is spilled in code generation?

Tags: design-patterns, tree, compiler-construction, cpu-registers

I am implementing a compiler using visitor pattern.

Here is the general algorithm I use.

`regs` gives the number of registers needed and `top` give the next free register.

```
generate(T,n) =
    if T is a leaf write ``load top(), T"
    if T is an internal node with children l and r then
    if regs(r) = 0 then { generate(l); write ``op top(), r" }
    else{
        generate(l,n)//Stored in Rn
        generate(r,n+1)//Stored in Rn+1
        write "op Rn, Rn+1" // rresult is stored in Rn
        push(R) }
```

But in the case where there's not enough registers, we need to spill variables.
Suppose we use a **greedy allocator** that **spills the last used register**. It means that, when we `generate(r)` if there's no register left to store the result, we **push Rn** to the stack and store result in Rn and then retrieve spilled variable to compute the operation.

The complete schema become:

```
generate(l,n)//Stored in Rn
push Rn // push to stack
generate(r,n)//Stored in Rn 
mov Rn R0 // move
pop Rn // retrieve from stack
write ``op Rn, R0" // result is stored in Rn
```

What I tried is to modifty the function `top` to make it return a register if any available and push last register before returning it if no-one is available so when generating `r` children, we can save to stack if there's no space...

```
generate(l,top())//Stored in Rn
generate(r,top())//Spill if no space and store in Rn 
mov Rn R0 <--- my problem is here
pop Rn <--- my problem is here
write ``op Rn, R0" <---my problem here
```

But after generation of `l` and `r`, how does the operation knows that it needs to **unspill*** some variable (if it has to) ?

My question is :

**Programmatically, how can I implement it in the compiler to make it oblivious to operation code.**

Ideally ... code should look like:

```
generate(l,something())//Stored in Rn
generate(r,something())
write ``op somethingelse(), againsomethingelse()" <--- taking into account when space is available or not
```

Comment: Typical graph colouring register allocators, for example, rebuild the interference graph if spilling occurs. So, they operate over a normalised (usually three-address code) format and use standard liveness algorithms to compute the interference - so if a value is spilled, the program is rewritten (to insert the spill code to commute the temporary to/from memory upon defs and uses), and the algorithm goes again. What you're implementing appears ad-hoc and of your own creation, so I can't comment on how you would incorporate spill awareness; like most things, probably more book keeping.

Comment: @contificate If we suppose that it is spilled using a complex strategy like graph coulouring...when backtracking operations, how does the compiler knows that a particular temp has been spilled and needs to be unspilled ? I think my (long) question sums up to that. Is there a known data structure used like a mapping from AST node to location in register/stack used by the compiler ?

Comment: That's the thing, spilling rewrites the program (so you don't need to remember what you spilled - but it's good to prioritise spill candidates). If you know you need to spill some temp, you rewrite its definitions and uses; you put a load before each use, and a store after each definition. The fact that uses immediately follow a definition (that loads the value from a stack slot) offloads the liveness (as definitions kill liveness). So, the interferences change and must be recomputed. Generally, you don't do this at the level of an AST - it's often over three address code for a basic block.

Answer (score 1):

The comments made by contificate are right. I'll just try to elaborate a little more.

First, I suggest you to read the following slides: [https://web.cs.wpi.edu/~kal/courses/compilers/module6/RastislavBodikregalloc.PDF](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/%7Ekal/courses/compilers/module6/RastislavBodikregalloc.PDF)

On slide number 28, you can see how spilling works. You enter a loop: try to assign the registers by coloring. If it fails, spill a register and try to coloring again. Repeat until you're successful.

How do you track which variable are spilled or not? You don't. When you rewrite the code to accommodate the spilling, you get for free the tracking. On slide 28 it says

> Before each operation that uses f, insert f := load fa

> After each operation that defines f, insert
> store f, fa

So if in your program, you have a

```
t2 = t0 + t1
...
t10 = t2 + t3
```

And by whatever reason you can't assign a register for temporary t2, this means that its interference graph is overloaded with too many edges. You need to eliminate some of those edges. How do you do that? By making a variable alive for less time. How do you achieve that? By inserting loads and stores as soon as you need to use the variable. So the example I gave becomes:

```
t2 = t0 + t1
store t2    // immediately stores t2 after its use
...
// loads t2 just right before it is used
t2 = load t2
t10 = t2 + t3
```

This way t2 is going to be alive just for a brief moment of time. This will reduce the pressure in the interference graph which will allow a new round trying to assign registers to the temporaries in a graph with fewer interferences. If can't again find a colouring, choose another temporary, spill it (insert loads and stores where needed) and repeat.

This is isn't the only way to do it, but I believe it is one of the simplest.